# Leverage and One-Out Model

Tags: regression, linear-algebra, leverage

I am currently trying to prove the following theorem, found within the course material from a Graduate Regression module. For context, here $X$  is the usual full-rank design matrix, estimators are found via OLS; postulates $P1-P4$ are:

1. residuals are centered
2. homoscedasticity
3. non-correlation of residuals
4. normality of residuals.

The theorem states:

> Assume X is full rank and [P1]–[P4]. Then we have for all i=1,··· ,n
>
> $$Y_i - \hat{Y}_i = (1 - h_{ii})(Y_i - \hat{Y}^P_i)$$
>
> where $\hat{Y}^P_i$ is the estimate for $Y_i$ computed without the $i^{th}$ row of $X$

I have developed some intuition of leverage being the influence of $Y_i$ on the corresponding estimate, but I would like to be able to deal with the problem with some more formality.